# Get everything after the prefix as a param with Deeplinking and React-Navigation-5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking, react-navigation-v5

I am using react-navigation-5 and deeplinking. I would like to extract everything after the deeplink prefix and pass it as a param.

I have the following

```
const deeplinking = {
    prefixes: ['myapp://'],
    config: {
      Store: {
        path:'store/:url' ,
        params: {
          url: null,      
        },
      }
  }
  };

  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={deeplinking}>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Splash" screenOptions={{ headerShown: false,   cardStyle: { backgroundColor: '#fff' } }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={Splash} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Store" component={Store} />

      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

If I use the following deep-link:

```
myapp://alpha/delta/gamma
```

The url parameter becomes:

```
'alpha'
```

So the first forward-slash `/` encountered after the prefix and everything after it is getting stripped out when the deeplink is passed.

I want the parameter (url in the above example), to be:

```
'alpha/delta/gamma'
```

How can I achieve this?

I have checked the docs here:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links/

But they do not mention how to deal with forward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
  config: {
    screens: {
      deeplink: {
        path: 'deeplink/id',
      },
    },
  },
}
Make deeplink url:
https://example.com/deeplink/details?token=uygiuhiuhpuihpiuyiuhuihhiluhiu

Access token from component:
this.props.route.params.token

result will be =uygiuhiuhpuihpiuyiuhuihhiluhiu
```